# which one of the following phrase is correct?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Which phrase is correct?

> - The shipped order has been dropped
> - The shipped order have been dropped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is:  ***The shipped order has been dropped.*** The other sentence is incorrect because the verb does not agree with the noun. If you wanted the second sentence to be correct, you would need to change the noun from singular to plural. Then the sentence would be:  ***The shipped orders have been dropped.***

Answer (score 0):

Correct:

`The shipped order has been dropped`

Incorrect:

`The shipped order have been dropped`

Corrected (pluralised orders):

`The shipped orders have been dropped`

Comment: OK, we now know which form is correct, but we didn't learn anything. Do you mind elaborating why that's so?